# With the Logitech K780 keyboard and Windows 10, how to capture and print the current window not the entire screen

Tags: logitech-keyboard

I would like to capture and print the current window (not the entire screen) when using the Logitech K780 keyboard with Windows 10.  What key combination should be used for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, you just need to press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> on your keyboard.

EDIT: Ok I can see there isn't a dedicated print screen button on your keyboard.

If you have the latest windows 10 updates, you can change the print screen key (in your case, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) to open screen snipping instead.

Open settings and search for `Print Screen` and you should see an option for print screen shortcut:

[image: settings for print screen]

This will allow you to grab the part of the screen you want when you press  <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for that nice workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Per the user manual the correct key combination is <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> for Windows 10.

Source: https://www.logitech.com/assets/64641/k780-online-setup-guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks. In the manual that keystroke combination is defined as "print screen". That's the reason I overlooked it. When I try it, it wants the user to draw a rectangle anywhere (rather than copying the currently active window) and then it moves the capture into the clipboard, and from there it can be printed from the [...] menu.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, it may happen that fn+del is assigned for some program.
Use however this combination in win10

shift+win key+S, the cursor will change to plus sign and you can capture a part of the screen to the clipboard, in your application just past and it is done.

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out to only print the current window and not the entire screen. Make sure your cursor is on the window/page you want to print screen. Click ctrl+fn+alt+del. The delete key should also have an icon with two squares referencing the print screen function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).